# How to display popup menu in Eclipse E4 MPart

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, e4

In Eclipse E4, detached view option is not available but this is very important requirement for our project, So i want to add popup menu in MPart to provide the functionality.

Please guide me how can i add popup menu in MPart. I tried adding it in application model but it seems i am doing something wrong.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a popup menu and handled menu item to the MPart in your .e4xmi
Make sure you get the id's correct. The handler will be the code you want to run

see here for an example:

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseRCP/article.html#menuadvanced_popup